# How can we create account users under super admin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can any one explain me how to create User Accounts under super admin with accesses and restrictions in ASP.Net MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this example in the asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7), which shows how to implement Membership and Authentication in MVC3 but this applies to MVC4 too.

You first need to setup your database for Membership

1. Create a SQL Database and call it what you want. If your application already uses one, you can use it for Membership too.
2. Assign and user and password to the Database.
3. Run the ASP.Net SQL Server Setup Wizard located in your .NET
   Framework directory. The wizard is called aspnet_regsql.exe.

You can find more information about this process in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Once you have setup Membership, you would be able to designate Actions or Controllers that only SuperAdmins will have access to.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Superadmin")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    // Controller code here
}
```

Comment: How can I setup Membership with database table. Roles come from data base table